# Случайный выбор переменной

Tags: java

У меня есть несколько Int переменных, мне надо что бы случайном образом из них выбралось одна, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Будьте добры показать ваш код и рассказать, что именно у вас не получилось сделать.

Comment: 1) Берете первую переменную и возвращаете ее. 2) Повторяете пункт 1. 3) говорите заказчику/начальнику/жене, что на то она и случайная величина, чтобы выбираться случайно, а значит с некоторой вероятностью может совпадать сколько угодно раз ))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @BOPOH отправила жена мужика принести из лесу случайное число на Новый Год...

Answer (score 8):

1. Поместите их в массив
2. Сгенерируйте случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до [размер массива] - 1
3. Достаньте значение из массива по индексу, полученному на предыдущем шаге

Answer (score 2):

можно так :

```
int [] mainInt = {105, 22 , 34, 463 ,51};
Random rand = new Random();
int result = mainInt[rand.nextInt(5)];
System.out.println(result);
```